# R - Applying a function recursively over a list in 'purrr' while preserving its structure

Tags: r, purrr

I have the following list:

```
my_list = split(1:3, letters[1:3]) %>% 
  map(as.list) %>% 
  str()

List of 3
 $ a:List of 1
  ..$ : int 1
 $ b:List of 1
  ..$ : int 2
 $ c:List of 1
  ..$ : int 3
```

I would like to set the `xyz` attribute of each element of the list *and* the list itself. I'm currently getting by with:

```
my_list = split(1:3, letters[1:3]) %>% 
  map(., ~.x %>% 
        as.list %>% 
        structure(xyz = T)) %>% 
  structure(xyz = T)
```

But I was wondering what I would have done had the list been deeper? Is there a way to apply a function recursively to achieve the above in `purrr`? I am aware of the `reduce` and `accumulate` functions and `rapply` in base but I don't think they do what I need in this case.

Also, trying rapply gave me:

```
my_list = rapply(my_list, function(x) structure(x, xyz = T), how = 'list') %>% str()
List of 3
 $ a:List of 1
  ..$ : int 1
  .. ..- attr(*, "xyz")= logi TRUE
 $ b:List of 1
  ..$ : int 2
  .. ..- attr(*, "xyz")= logi TRUE
 $ c:List of 1
  ..$ : int 3
  .. ..- attr(*, "xyz")= logi TRUE
```

Which seems to get me close to the desired result. But `attr(my_list, 'xyz')` and `attr(my_list$a, 'xyz')` both yield `NULL`, why is this? Both `attr(my_list, 'xyz')` and `attr(my_list$a, 'xyz')` are `TRUE` for the outcome of the pipeline included earlier in my post.

Comment: Would `map_depth()` be of any help?

Comment: @meriops I think `map_depth()` is used to apply functions to elements at a specific depth in a list so I'm not sure how it would apply here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We could define a recursive function to add an attribute to every (nested) `list` *and* to every nested `list` element.

```
recursive_add_attr <- function(this) {
    if (is.list(this))
        structure(map(this, recursive_add_attr), xyz = TRUE)
    else
        structure(this, xyz = TRUE)
}

out <- recursive_add_attr(my_list)
str(out)
#List of 3
# $ a:List of 1
#  ..$ : int 1
#  .. ..- attr(*, "xyz")= logi TRUE
#  ..- attr(*, "xyz")= logi TRUE
# $ b:List of 1
#  ..$ : int 2
#  .. ..- attr(*, "xyz")= logi TRUE
#  ..- attr(*, "xyz")= logi TRUE
# $ c:List of 1
#  ..$ : int 3
#  .. ..- attr(*, "xyz")= logi TRUE
#  ..- attr(*, "xyz")= logi TRUE
# - attr(*, "xyz")= logi TRUE
```

This will also work for `list`s of arbitrary depth and nest structure:

```
my_list2 <- list(
    a = list(A1 = 1, A2 = list(2, 3)),
    b = list(B1 = 4, B2 = list(5, 6)))
out2 <- recursive_add_attr(my_list2)
str(out2)
#List of 2
# $ a:List of 2
#  ..$ A1: num 1
#  .. ..- attr(*, "xyz")= logi TRUE
#  ..$ A2:List of 2
#  .. ..$ : num 2
#  .. .. ..- attr(*, "xyz")= logi TRUE
#  .. ..$ : num 3
#  .. .. ..- attr(*, "xyz")= logi TRUE
#  .. ..- attr(*, "xyz")= logi TRUE
#  ..- attr(*, "xyz")= logi TRUE
# $ b:List of 2
#  ..$ B1: num 4
#  .. ..- attr(*, "xyz")= logi TRUE
#  ..$ B2:List of 2
#  .. ..$ : num 5
#  .. .. ..- attr(*, "xyz")= logi TRUE
#  .. ..$ : num 6
#  .. .. ..- attr(*, "xyz")= logi TRUE
#  .. ..- attr(*, "xyz")= logi TRUE
#  ..- attr(*, "xyz")= logi TRUE
# - attr(*, "xyz")= logi TRUE
```

Comment: Thank you @Maurits! I never knew functions could be called recursively like that.